# How to save stacks in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-activity, bundle

I have some stacks and want to preserve them using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). There are only basic things are available to put in the SharedPreferences. Is there any easy way to preserve complex / custom data structures as well?

Comment: As Marcus suggests in his answer, your only option for this is to convert your data structures into something that goes in a `String`: JSON, XML, etc. `SharedPreferences` is not really a general-purpose data storage system -- for that, use a database or some other sort of file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Gson](https://github.com/pchauhan/StoreandRetrieveObjectClassDemo), you can easily save custom objects to `SharedPreferences`

Save:

```
 Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson("MyObject");
 prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
 prefsEditor.commit();
```

Load:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go with Marcus answer. Here is what I did in my project :

store in shared prefs:

```
       SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
          String json = gson.toJson(MyImages);
          edit.putString("MyImages", json);
```

Retreive from shared prefs:

```
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).getString("MyImages", "");
     ArrayList<String> MyImages= new ArrayList<String>();
     MyImages=gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);
```

This way you will also not loose the structure of your data (if it is in some order).

If you put Map directly into shared prefs, you will loose the order of data when you retrieve the Map. To me sequence was important and gson+Arraylist worked just fine.

Another way is not use SharedPrefs and store data in file(internal memory):

```
File file = new File(getDir("data", MODE_PRIVATE), "map");    
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
outputStream.writeObject(map);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```